# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Iam new to React this is my first Simple small project . Iam getting this error and I found the reason why it is happening. But I don't know where my code repeatedly rendering that particular component. please help me to tackle this issue.

````
function Button(props)
{  
  return(<button onClick={props.count(props.value)}>{props.value}</button>);
}
function Display(props)
{
  return(<div>{props.messege}</div>);
}
function App()
{
  const[counter,setCounter]=useState(0);
  const countfunction=(val)=> setCounter(counter+val);
  return(
  <div>
      <Button count={countfunction} value={10} />
      <Button count={countfunction} value={5} />
      <Button count={countfunction} value={1} />
      <Button count={countfunction} value={120} />
      <Display messege={counter}/>
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('mountNode'));```
````

This is my error state

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
    at checkForNestedUpdates 
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber 
    at dispatchAction 
    at Object.countfunction [as count] 
    at Button 
    at renderWithHooks 
    at updateFunctionComponent 
    at beginWork 
    at beginWork$1 
    at performUnitOfWork
```

Comment: <button onClick={()=>props.count(props.value)}>{props.value}</button>

Comment: the issue occurred due to the instant call from button onClick, just add an arrow function there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the offending line

```
return(<button onClick={props.count(props.value)}>{props.value}</button>);
```

This is because the function is being called on render, instead of when it is clicked, to get it to only run on click you need to wrap it in an anonymous function, like so...

```
return(<button onClick={() => props.count(props.value)}>{props.value}</button>);
```